# Texture mapping in a ray tracing for sphere in C++

Tags: c++, textures, texture-mapping, raytracing

[image]

I have set up a simple ray tracing in C++. I wanted to add the texture mapping to the sphere. It basically just map the texture from a PPM file to the sphere. Below are my code for the part.

```
//Call shaderay from trace ray function
// index_of_winning_object = index of scene object array
// point = intersection point
Color shadeRay (int index_of_winning_object, Vect point, Ray ray){

double final_index2;    

//if no intersection, return the background color (double confirm)
if (index_of_winning_object == -1) {
    return bkgcolor;
}else{

    Vect c = scene_objects[index_of_winning_object].getSphereCenter();
    Vect p = point;

    //Normal to the intersection point and sphere
    Vect N = p.vectSub(c).normalize();

    //Calculating the texture coordinate for a sphere
    double temp = acos(N.getVectZ());
    double temp2 = atan2(N.getVectY(), N.getVectX());
    //u,v 
    double v = temp / 3.141592653589793;

    if (temp2 < 0) {
        temp2 = temp2 + (2 * 3.141592653589793);
    }

    double u = temp2 / (2 * 3.141592653589793);

    // get_ppm_width = width of the sample texture ppm file like (picture.ppm)
    // get_ppm_height = height of the sample texture ppm file like (picture.ppm)

    int width = u * get_ppm_width;
    int height = v * get_ppm_height;        


    //calculating the pixel of the ppm file, I store the pixel in get_array in RGB struct
    // ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___
    //  0   1   2   3   4   5   6
    //  7   8   9  10   11  12  13
    // ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___
    // above is the example of the get_array. get_array is a one dimensional array of RGB struct

    int px = height + (width * get_ppm_width);

    // Get the color from the get_array 
    Color final (get_array[px].r, get_array[px].g, get_array[px].b );

    return final;
  }
}
```

Can somebody please let me know what I have done wrong for the shaderay function? Thanks a lot
Top left is the picture of the sphere I got. While the bottom the texture of world map.[image]

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot? Having a better understanding of what you're getting and what you're hoping to achieve would help.

Comment: @Liam M I tried to upload, but I couldn't as I don't have enough reputation to post a pic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calculating N, try calculating (u, v) using this algorithm:

```
u = 0.5 + arctan2(dz, dx) / (2*pi)
v = 0.5 - arcsin(dy) / pi
```

I suspect that's your problem.

Try to isolate your problem by generating a colour solely using your UV coordinates, rather than picking them from the texture. You could try:

```
int red = u % 255;
int green = 0;
int blue = 0;
```

Examine the results. Are they what you'd expect to see?

Comment: I would pretty sure the calculation is correct as it was given by my professor. However, I have tried, and it gave me the same wrong image. Can you tell me, if possible, my algorithm for shaderay is correct? Thanks

Comment: In what way is the image incorrect? Here's a suggestion: rather than picking the pixel from the PPM, try generating the colour procedurally  (as a function of (u,v)) to ensure that your UV mappings are correct and isolate the code below that as the source of your problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But can you explain more about how to generate the color procedurally? I have no clue on how to do this. Thanks

Comment: See amended answer :).

Comment: I tried and it produces a sphere which red in color.

Comment: Are your RGB values measured from 0 - 255 or from 0.0 - 1.0? I think you can appreciate the approach I'm advocating.

Comment: 0-255. What picture it was supposed to generated?

Comment: It should generate a shading pattern across the sphere showing the change in u coordinate. It appears there is an error in your UV calculations, or somewhere above that. I'm afraid that I can't give you much more help than I have: you need to go through each of the parts of your code and ensure each one is correct (write tests and make sure they give you the results you expect), and you should find the error.

Comment: hello, I have attached a current pic of the output. Can you please take a look?